# Show that $\prod (1- P(A_n))=0$ iff $\sum P(A_n) = \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, infinite-product

Let $A_n$ be independent events with $P(A_n) \neq 1$. Show that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- P(A_n))=0$ iff $\sum P(A_n) = \infty$

It kind of looks obvious but I really have no idea how to prove it. Can someone give me help?

Comment: It directly follows from the first and second Borel-Cantelli lemmas.

Comment: I still don't understand how I can derive this directly from Borel-Cantelli lemma. Thanks

Comment: On second thoughts, I think only the second one is useful here. Please give me some time to type an answer.

Comment: Posted the answer. Turns out both Borel-Cantelli lemmas are useful :)

Comment: possibly related exercise if interested: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524353/exercise-fromdavid-williams-probability-with-martingales-chap-4-3

Comment: Hint: I was able to answer it without directly using either BCL, but I followed the BCL2 proof to prove it.

Comment: Borel-Cantelli lemmas are not involved in the proof of this result.

Comment: OP: 18 minutes.

Comment: It may be that the Borel-Cantelli lemma is the best way to prove this, but we should also not that the statement doesn't require any concepts from probability to be understood.  It just says that if $0\le p_n\le 1$ for all $n$ then $\prod_n (1-p_n)=0$ iff $\sum_n p_n=\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy For the reason why Borel-Cantelli lemma is NOT the best way to prove this, see my comment on karakusc's answer.

Comment: @Did : If I'd been more attentive, I might have thought of that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The proof of this result has nothing to do with probability theory in general or with Borel-Cantelli lemmas in particular, it is only plain-old-deterministic real analysis:

> Let $(x_n)$ denote a real valued sequence such that $0\leqslant x_n\lt1$ for every $n$, then $\prod\limits_n(1-x_n)=0$ if and only if $\sum\limits_nx_n$ diverges.

Proof: If $\sum\limits_nx_n$ diverges, note that $\log(1-x)\leqslant-x$ for every $x\lt1$ to deduce that $$\prod\limits_n(1-x_n)=\exp\left(\sum_n\log(1-x_n)\right)\leqslant\exp\left(-\sum_nx_n\right)=0.$$
If $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges, note that $x_n\leqslant\frac12$ for every $n$ large enough, say every $n\geqslant N$, and that $\log(1-x)\geqslant-2x$ for every $x\leqslant\frac12$ to deduce that $$\prod\limits_{n\geqslant N}(1-x_n)=\exp\left(\sum_{n\geqslant N}\log(1-x_n)\right)\geqslant\exp\left(-2\sum_{n\geqslant N}x_n\right),$$ hence $$\prod\limits_{n\geqslant N}(1-x_n)\ne0.$$ Since $x_n\lt1$ for every $n$, in particular for every $n\lt N$, this implies the desired result, namely, that $$\prod\limits_n(1-x_n)\ne0.$$

Comment: Did: nice proof! +1

Comment: @Did this related? I used ln(1-x) too http://math.stackexchange.com/q/524353/140308

Comment: If it is indeed related, then you should know I followed the BC2 proof. This proof also looks like the BC2 proof sooo....yeah...it's not used, but the proof does help. Well for YOU, you didn't need it but yeah others might :))

Comment: @BCLC ?? Of course this is "related" since this is the same question! Hence one can copy the approach in the present answer and it will work, yes. (Sorry but what "should I know" that I would not, exactly?)

Comment: @Did Hey it's not the same but thanks for pointing out that they are equivalent :p You said that the proof has nothing to do with BCs when it actually could since I followed the BC2 proof to prove the other question. Of course some one as brilliant as you could just come up with the proof independently

Comment: @BCLC No. What I actually wrote is that "Borel-Cantelli lemmas are not involved in the proof of this result'. This does not mean that knowing a proof of BCL cannot help to find a proof of this and, indeed, it does since the proof of BCL is basically a proof of this result. But to use the conclusion of BCL in a proof of this result is absurd. (Your insistence about this point is surprising, the matter seems settled since my comment to karakusc's answer Sep 29 at 14:06. But if your point is that the inequality $\log(1-x)\leqslant-x$ is useful, then I fully agree.)

Comment: See what you also wrote in the first sentence of your answer. "Nothing to do" =/= "does not use". In fact I'd say "Nothing to do" $\supseteq$ "does not use" :))

Comment: @BCLC Yes I see what I wrote in the first sentence of my answer and it is correct. Sorry but I fail to see where this discussion is going, so, if you have no specific maths question about this...

Answer (score 4):

By the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, if $A_n$ are independent and $\sum P(A_n) = \infty$, then $P(A_n \text{ infinitely often})=1$. Then

$$
0=P \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c\right) = \prod_{i=1}^\infty (1- P \left( A_n\right))
$$

since this is the probability that none of $A_n$ would happen.

Conversely, if $\sum P(A_n) < \infty$, by first Borel-Cantelli lemma, $P(A_n \text{ infinitely often})=0$, meaning a.s. there exists $N<\infty$ such that $A_n$ does not happen for $n >N$. Therefore

$$
\begin{split}
\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1- P \left( A_n\right)) &=P \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c\right) \\
&= P \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^N A_n^c\right) \\
& =E_N \left[ E\left[ \left.1_{\bigcap_{n=1}^N A_n^c}\right| N\right]\right] \\
& =E_N \left[ E\left[ \left. \prod_{n=1}^N 1_{A_n^c}\right| N\right]\right] \\
& =E_N \left[ \prod_{n=1}^N E\left[ \left. 1_{A_n^c}\right| N\right]\right] \\
& =E_N \left[ \prod_{n=1}^N P(A_n^c)\right] > 0\\
\end{split}
$$
since $P(A_n^c)>0$ for all $n$, and $N<\infty$. ($1_{(\cdot)}$ denotes indicator function in the above).

Perhaps cleaner and a bit more rigorous solutions are possible.

Comment: Funny: this is using Borel-Cantelli lemma to prove a crucial step of the proof of Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: I don't quite catch the implication that $P(A_n \text{infinitely often}) = 0$ implies the existence of a specific finite $N$ for which $A_n$ a.s. doesn't occur beyond $N$.  Is it a compactness argument?

Comment: @ErickWong : If there is no value $N$ such that $A_n$ is false for all $n\ge N$, then there are infinitely many values of $n$ for which $A_n$ is true.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I completely agree for a given state, but maybe I'm misinterpreting the first two lines of the chain of equalities.  Is $N$ meant to be fixed or is it a random variable?

Comment: @ErickWong $N$ is a random variable in general, but we know that $P(N<\infty)=1$.

Comment: It is random, since it depends on the occurrence or non-occurrence of $A_n$ for all values of $n$. ${}\qquad{}$